# Angular CLI: npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I am trying to create angular app using **ng new testApp -routing** but throws below error.

**Command:**

```
ng new testApp -routing
```

**Error:**

> npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

Anyone has an idea about this error

Comment: I don't know if it's the cause of your problem, but it should be `--routing`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typo: you need to use `--`:

```
ng new testApp --routing
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try `npm rebuild` and then `ng new testApp --routing`

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer